# How to create primary key when online and local MySQL database need to sync

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am developing a inventory software with **MySQL and PHP** where local database will sync to online database.

Suppose i have a table sell and sell_id is the primary key of the table. I usually use INT and auto increment with primary key.

In **local database 1** sell table has 2 entry(sell_id 1,2) and **local database 2** sell table has 2 entry(sell_id 1,2).

If i sync/insert these 2 local sell table entries to online sell table it will become (sell_id 1,2,3,4).

As sell id changes it effects those entries in other table which are using sell_id as foreign key.

[image]

How should i plan to create primary key in this situation.

I am planning to use **alpha-numeric** id which will be unique for both database. Will it create any problem or slow my db query further for millions of sell_id??

[image]

Are there any other ways to solve the problem ?

Comment: use a procedure to select all the content to be imported from local db, then change the id to the new sell_id and make the proper inserts. Or create a trigger to change all the sell_id's

Comment: Shouldn't make much odds, performance wise, if your primary key is an `INT` or `CHAR` - there are certain foibles with `VARCHAR` and `MyISAM` tables though but nothing too horrendous. Your biggest issue is likely to be generating that value in the first place.

Comment: You could have an extra column identifying the client and use <client id, local auto_increment> as primary key. That way you will know whence a given tuple comes from. But it is not clear to me whether these tuples may refer to the same *object*; in which case you might need something equivalent to a SKU. For purchases, etc., the <ClientId, TupleId> should work. For customers, you would also need a two-way sync of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Often, when you have a replicated system, the goal is to maintain the same data on all servers.  That does not seem to be your business requirement.

Instead, you might consider having a composite primary key on all the servers.  This would combine the auto incremented primary key with a server id.  All tables referencing the foreign key would need to incorporate the "server" column as well as the "id".

In general, I'm not a fan of composite primary keys.  However, you have a distributed database and need to identify the specific database "partition" where the data is located.  This seems like a good use-case for composite primary keys.

An alternative approach -- if you are willing to take the risk -- is to set the auto numbering to a different start value on each server.  Use a big int and a big value such as 1,000,000,000,000 for one server, 2,000,000,000,000 for the next, and so on.  My preference is to have the "server" explicitly represented as a column, however.

Comment: I like the compound key approach here; just have to ensure that's replicated across all systems if/when a new server is added to the "cluster" (not really the right word but I can't think of a better one right now).